# url for multiplie categories and tags for seo optimization

Tags: laravel, vue.js, seo

for seo optimization, I need to change url, if I choose category or tag

`Route::post('/filter', [GalleryController::class, 'getByFilter'])->name('filter');`

```
 filter() {
            let vm = this
            vm.showLoader = true;
            const filters = {
                tags: vm.selectedTags,
                categories: vm.selectedCategories
            }
            axios.post('/gallery/filter', filters).then(response => {
                vm.showLoader = false;
                console.log(response);
                vm.products = response.data.data;
            })

        },
```

```
 public function getByFilters($slugs)
  {
      $categories = $slugs['categories'] ?? [];
      $tags = $slugs['tags'] ?? [];
      return Model::query()
          ->where('is_active', true)
          ->when($categories, function ($query) use ($categories) {
              $query->whereHas('categories', fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereIn('slug', $categories));
          })
          ->when($tags, function ($query) use ($tags) {
              $query->whereHas('tags', fn (Builder $query) => $query->whereIn('slug', $tags));
          })
          ->paginate(self::PAGINATE_LIMIT);
  }
```

I tried change url on laravel side, like this

```
      $urlParameters = [];

      if (!empty($categories)) {
          $urlParameters['categories'] = implode(',', $categories);
      }

      if (!empty($tags)) {
          $urlParameters['tags'] = implode(',', $tags);
      }

      $finalUrl = "/gallery/filter?" . http_build_query($urlParameters);
      $testUrl = '/gallery/filter/test';
      return redirect($testUrl);
```

and I tried to change url on Vue side, but idk how better and how correct

Comment: The issue at this point is unclear to me. Is your attempt failing or do you seek for the improvement of a solution that works?

Comment: @LajosArpad i tried any options to resolve this problem, but no nothing work for me.
i need find solution, to add cetegories and tags to url for seo

Comment: I do not understand the problem at this point. I need to understand what your problem is in order to be able to help.